# UAC Quiet Mode & Recycle Bin

Tags: windows-7, uac

When running UAC on Windows 7 in so-called "quiet-mode" (automatic "Yes" to UAC prompts on Admin accounts), Delete operations on restricted files (where the Delete option is marked with the UAC shield) display no Recycle Bin prompt, and instead delete instantly.

Normal (non-restricted) files display the Recycle Bin prompt as usual.

Is there a way to force displaying the Recycle Bin deletion prompt on UAC-protected files?

This is especially an issue for cases where (for privacy or security reasons) the Recycle Bin has been disabled, and files are deleted permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Know this is an oldie, but this one bugged me in the past with a few specific scenarios as well.  Easy fix, force it to always show the confirmation dialog.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

Create a DWord called "ConfirmFileDelete", set it to 1.  The "instant delete" thing is no longer happening.

Comment: I replaced "System" with "Explorer" at the end and kept the rest the same, which works for Win10 